# Bash script variable with if else statement but with loop

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression

I am not very experienced with bash scripting. But I am trying to validate individual xml files with corresponding xsd files in a directory. The beginning name does not change but the dates changes.

For example:

- File1.xsd
- File2.xsd
- File3.xsd
- File1_random_date.xml (random date time can be 2016_06_12_10_38_13)
- File2_random_date.xml
- File2_random_date.xml
- File3_random_date.xml

I would like validate all File2*.xml files against File2.xsd and all File1*.xml against File1.xsd etc etc

something like:

```
xmllint --noout --schema File2.xsd File2_*.xml
xmllint --noout --schema File1.xsd File1_*.xml
```

But i am not sure how to have regex string maybe for dates and say if File2_*.xml exist, validates each file against File2.xsd.

Any help please?

Comment: The shell doesn't (usually) use regular expressions. It uses shell globs, where `*` represents zero of more characters and `?` represents a single character. Just like you're using them in your Question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may help (using `bash`):

```
# Iterate across the XSD files
for xsdfile in *.xsd
do
    test -f "$xsdfile" || continue

    # Strip the ".xsd" suffix and search for XML files matching this prefix
    prefix="${xsdfile%.xsd}"
    for xmlfile in "$xsdfile"_*.xml
    do
        test -f "$xmlfile" || continue
        xmllint --noout --schema "$xsdfile" "$xmlfile"
    done
done
```

If you want to check all the matching XML files in a single operation, this would work:

```
# Iterate across the XSD files
for xsdfile in *.xsd
do
    test -f "$xsdfile" || continue

    # Strip the ".xsd" suffix and search for XML files matching this prefix
    prefix="${xsdfile%.xsd}"
    for xmlfile in "$xsdfile"_*.xml
    do
        # Skip if no files, else do it just once
        test -f "$xmlfile" || continue
        xmllint --noout --schema "$xsdfile" "$xsdfile"_*.xml
        break
    done       
done
```

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
list=(file*_*.xml)
for prefix (${(u)list%%_*})
  xmllint --noout --schema $prefix.xsd ${prefix}_*.xml
```

Comment: You should explain more about how your commands work, rather than just posting commands.